# CSS issue - div id isn't showing up on website

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a main div named "backhead" that has a background image with other divs inside. The main div doesn't show on my website (using Chrome Inspect to troubleshoot). The div isn't there, as if the name is spelled wrong, or a colon is missing, etc.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? Here's my code (all other div class and ids are working fine):

CSS file:

```
#backhead {
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("images/headerbackground.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.toplogo {
float:left;
padding:1.25em 0;
position:relative;
}

.rightinfo{
float:right;
width:61%;
position:relative;
}
```

In the PHP file:

```
<div id="backhead">
  <div class="toplogo">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/headerlogo.png"></div>
    <div class="rightinfo">
      <h2>Personal Specialist</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The div isn't there"? When you inspect the source you don't see `<div id="backhead">`? The code you posted works fine, so we'll need you to post a [mcve] that re-creates the issue.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the HTML and CSS code you posted. See: http://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/GNjKBj. 

If the div is not in the Element inspector at all, then you're not opening the file correctly, or you included it wrong. 

If it is showing in the element inspector and you're not seeing it in the page, then you need to post the rest of the HTML/CSS.

Comment: Nothing wrong, except for missing a closing `</div>` tag for `<div id="backhead">`...

Comment: I meant the div id "backhead" is not in the Element inspector at all. The div does shows on the site, however the background image is not there because there's an error somewhere. I did minimize the code and it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> height:100%;
> ```

This will work only if the parent element has height specified. If it is inside of autoheighted element, it would be replaced by `auto` and became `0` if there is no content.

Check for

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

if the element is placed directly in the `body`.

Comment: The element should still be visible in the Chrome inspector then.

Answer (score 0):

Even if that CSS was invalid the div should still show up within the markup. I ran the code on jsfiddle and it showed up fine. This leads me to believe that you may just need to clear your cache especially id you're hosting this on real server.

Try running it in a Chrome Incognito mode and see what happens.

Comment: I cleared the cache and still no change. But I did update my code and comments above. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's some type of weird server config or file type issue. Do you have this problem still if you change the file-type from PHP to HTML?

Comment: Also, if this is a PHP file and there is some PHP code in there - if there is a PHP syntax error it will sometimes just load a blank page and nothing else. So if you do have PHP in there, then try and turn PHP errors on.

Comment: Also I just noticed, you are missing a closing tag in your HTML. It shouldn't matter really, but it could be the problem.

Comment: Try 

<div id="backhead">
  <div class="toplogo">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/headerlogo.png"></div>
    <div class="rightinfo">
      <h2>Personal Specialist</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. I tried all the things you mentioned without success. For now, I'm using div style element to recreate what I wanted the css file to do and that is working. I still am not sure why the div id wouldn't work. I even tried a div class instead and changed the div id name. I'm stumped.